# In DSA digital signature, why does k have to be random and unique each for each signing?

Tags: dsa, elgamal-signature

If we repeat `k`, I think there is little chance for `s` to repeat since user's private key `x` is random which is also used to calculate `s`.

Comment: As for _repeated_ $k$ (not merely _biased_ $k$), you learn two linear equations $s_1 = (h_1 + r_1 x) k^{-1}$ and $s_2 = (h_2 + r_2 x) k^{-1}$ in two unknowns $k^{-1}$ and $x$; I'll leave solving for $x$ as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage I know how to calculate, but `mod q` is also a part of `s`. How can attacker know the left part without `mod q`?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Does attacks need to guess what is before `mod q`?

Comment: I don't understand your followup questions.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Your formula for `s` isn't correct because there is also `mod q`! Not sure if you ignored that intentionally. So you are assuming attackers know the left part, which isn't the case.

Comment: Everything in the formulas is to be interpreted modulo $q$, and you most certainly do know the necessary $s$ and $r$ values—they make up the signature.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Of course anyone knows `s` value, but it is after `mod q`. For the `s_1` and `s_2` equations you provided, will people be able to learn them?

Comment: The _premise_ is that you have two signatures: $(r_1, s_1)$ on a message $m_1$, and $(r_2, s_2)$ on a message $m_2$.  They both satisfy the signature equation $r_i = (g^{H(m_i) s_i^{-1}} y^{r_i s_i^{-1}} \bmod p) \bmod q$, where $g$ is the standard base point and $y = g^x$ is the public key with secret key $x$.  If you also know that the signatures were generated by the standard signing algorithm but $k$ is the same for both of them, then you know that $s_i \equiv (H(m_i) + r_i x) k^{-1} \pmod q$, which you can solve for $k^{-1}$ and $x$ using straightforward linear algebra.